# Audio call with peerJs without webview in Android

Tags: android, call, peerjs

Can we use peerJs for audio call without using webview in Android?
I just wanted make audio call application with peerJs library. But I don't want to use webview with attached to one single activity.
Although I am ok with dynamic app level webview that can handle call events on anywhere in app.
Is there any idea how to implement this in Android?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge we can not use peerjs with Webview in android